# AKKA - SCALA installation - Error

Tags: windows, zip, akka

I downloaded typesafe activtor from the 
http://www.lightbend.com/community/core-tools/activator-and-sbt
site. Clicked 'Get Started with Activator'

A Zip file got download - Unzipped and Double clicked the activator.bat

Error - Windows Cannot Find C:Users\at\Downloads\Typesafe-activator... Make sure you type the name correctly and try again'

What am I doing wrong here ? Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question draws little attention :) .. thats fine...

Here is the method I followed. Now its working

1. Install Eclipse for Scala(with SCALA and JRE)
2. Created new scala Project.
3. Extract the Akka Zip file - copy the folder location in clipboard
4. Goto Eclipse right click on Project name -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> libraries -> Add External JARs -> *Paste the folder location* --> Goto 'lib' -> select scala-library-2.11.jar . Click Open(This JAR file will be added)
5. Again click on Add External JARs -> goto 'lib' --> Akka --> Select all the jars and -> Click OPEN.
6. Now create a scala APP under Prject_name --> SRC folder
7. paste the sample code - I used the helloActor code from the below link

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/simple-scala-akka-actor-examples-hello-world-actors.

8. Right Click -> Run as -> Scala Application.

It Worked For Me. Hope It will work for you too.. (If you have same issue).